# How add list values in single one line command in ansible?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I would like to add values of a list in a single shell command. How is that possible?

My List definded as a variable in my ansible.yaml:

```yaml
test:
  list:
     - /etc/a
     - /etc/b
     - /etc/c
```

With the above list I would like to get something like this when ansible is running

`ffmpeg /etc/a /etc/b/ /etc/c`

ffmpeg is just a sample..

How i need to configure my playbook task?

```yaml
- name: Command
  shell: ffmpeg ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `join` filter:

```
- name: Command
  shell: ffmpeg {{ test.list | join(' ') }}
```

Comment: possible to add an argument for example -d before each list item?

Comment: @sokolata please edit your question and make it accurate. The current answer is 100% exact regarding your current question. Else accept this answer then ask a new question. Meanwhile, have a look at the `map` filter which you can use with `regex_replace` to ad the option to each list element prior to joining them.